# Should I report players who lie about their language preference?

Tags: dota-2

Despite selecting "EU West" as home server and only selecting "English" in the matchmaking options I still end up in teams consisting of me and 4 non-English speakers.

Should I report those players for "Communication Abuse"?

Comment: Yes you should, i hate this too. It's a team game and if this happens a lot the match making system should get fixed.

Comment: There aren't any laid out rules for the report system, unfortunately.

Comment: EU only has a few counties which main language is english, but most of them can speak a little and understand english. But that doesn't force them to speak english...

Comment: although it sucks that this happens to a lot of people, I know a group of Chinese kids based in Europe who are forced to use EU West to avoid lag but aren't great at English. When they select any other language under their preferences, they can't find any matches.
Edit: Not defending people that do this, just pointing out another angle to the argument.

Comment: I don't think all languages are covered under "language preference" are they? I think they have around 3-4 options, but there are thousands of languages that people speak in, so can't really report them for that.